# Can I apply for adsense for a website with iframe?

Tags: google-adsense, iframe, google-adsense-policies

Can I apply for adsense if my website is showing another website content in iframe? What if the other website contains copyrighted material?

Comment: Is that the only thing your site is showing?  Could you disable that site feature while applying if needed?  Is the purpose of your site more than to put an advertisement beside somebody else's content?

Comment: No, My website shows lot of other valid contents., non-copyrighted content. But was wondering if my website could be banned if I use iframe to show other website's content to show some other information. I may not know if it will be copyrighted or not. and again., even links of a copyrighted material will ban me from adsense right?